# how can write htaccess file to display user friendly url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I developed one website. I want to display url for my website as below.

```
http://example.com/1/post
```

i am passing the query string as below

```
<a href="page.php?id=1&url=post>click me</a>
```

I wrote a below htaccess file to display above user friendly url

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?id=([0-9]*)&url=(.+)\sHTTP  [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]*)/(.+)$ /page\.php\?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

But, when clicking Click me link, it load some time and display cannot reach message in browser. I dont no what is wrong in my htaccess code. Kindly help me to display url as i mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]
```